# MS Teams outgoing webhook

Tags: powershell, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I try to validate the HMAC from an outgoing MS Teams Webhook with PowerShell.

```
# Validate Message
$enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$message = $Request.Body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
$message = $enc.GetBytes($message)
$secret = '<Security token from the ougoing webhook>'

$hmacsha = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256
$hmacsha.key = [Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($secret)
$signature = $hmacsha.ComputeHash([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($message))
$signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($signature)
$signaturesend = ($Request.Headers.authorization.Split(" "))[1]

If ($signature -eq $signaturesend){
  Write-Host "Authenticated"
}
else {
    Write-Host "Not authenticated"
}
```

But the authorisation in the header is never the same as I calculate it. What should be the message part to calculate the HMAC?

```
$message = $Request.Body.text
```

does also not work.

Thanks for your help.

Best Reagrds,
Daniel

Comment: Hi @Daniel Fuhrer, could you please share the error message.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Fuhrer, are you still facing the issue, could you please share the error message

Comment: Hi @Daniel Fuhrer, are you still facing the issue ?

Comment: Hi
Sorry for the delay. 
Yes I have still the issue. So there is no error message. 
In the header of the outgoing webhook, is an authentication field. What I try to do is to validate the request, with the posted code. But the HMAC is never the same. Do I do a mistake in the calculation? What do I have to use to calculate it? The whole body seems to be wrong ($Request.Body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100).
Thanks for any hint.